# Put Values in Multidimensional Array keys

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

```
$firstarray = array("first"=>'pakistan',"second"=>'bangladesh',"third"=>'');
```

I have array like above some keys have value and some keys don't have value. so i want to search this array and place **no** for those keys which don't have value.

**The result which i want:**

```
$newfirstarray = array("first"=>'pakistan',"second"=>'bangladesh',"third"=>'No');
```

I search on the web find functions like `array_filter()` , `array_map()`. i don't know either it work with this

**My Little Try**

```
$firstarray = array("first"=>'pakistan',"second"=>'bangladesh',"third"=>'');


foreach($firstarray as $keyx){
    if($keyx==''){
        $keyx='no'; //sorry for this example, at this point i don't know how to put values.
        print_r($firstarray );
    }
}
```

This code shows me original array and not putting no as a value for third key.

Comment: Added the proper `foreach()` below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loop through your array and check if the value is equal to `""` if yes replace it with `no`:

```
$result = array_map(function($v){$v == "" ? "no" : $v;}, $array);
```

Comment: Huh, didn't know str_replace() takes arrays. That's a much better answer than mine. :)

Comment: @JoelHinz search, replacement and the subject parameter can take an array as argument. Many people don't know this about str_replace() even though it's documented in the manual.

Comment: Yeah, I knew about the first two params, but I haven't read the documentation for that function in a very long time. :)

Answer (score 4):

It's probably easiest to just run a foreach loop by reference, like this:

```
foreach ($array as $key => &$val) {
    if ($key == '') {
        $val = 'No';
    }
}
```

The `&` means that you assign the value by reference, so it can be assigned from right within the loop.

Edit: Since you want a new array instead, you can easily do this:

```
$new = array();
foreach ($array as $key => $val) {
    if ($val == '') {
        $val = 'No';
    }
    $new[$key] = $val;
}
```

That way, you just go through the first array and create a new one on-the-fly.

Comment: then how i can make new array which have value no for keys. and then print_r it?

Comment: Not getting third value for third key.

Comment: when i print_r($new) it shows me original array with blank value for third key.

Comment: Don't check `$key` check `$val`.

Comment: Oops, thanks. Anyway, I'd suggest accepting Rizier's answer.

Answer (score 1):

I love the `str_replace()` but since you mentioned `array_map()`:

```
$newfirstarray = array_map(function($v){ return empty($v) ? 'No' : $v; }, $firstarray);
```

The proper `foreach()` would be:

```
foreach ($firstarray as $key => $val) {
    $newfirstarray[$key] = empty($val) ? 'No' : $val;
}
```

Comment: And I always thought you were in love with `array_column()` ;)

Comment: @Rizier123:  I love array_column() more!  :-)